# Why does Ubuntu One android not sync video

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, android, cloud, photo

I have U1 android client and have auto-upload photos on. So far so good, photos all upoaded to cloud folder...a new photo taken uploads right away. The problem is any phone capable of running android (ie smartphone), not only takes photos but video as well. How do I get my video to sync with cloud as well as photo?

Comment: I came across this bug report today, about this very issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-files/+bug/1168641 The more people subscribe to it, the more likely it will get noticed.

Answer (score 5):

We are only syncing pictures at the moment because the API the Android client uses has not been yet optimised for large files (mostly it doesn't support resuming failed uploads).
Because videos are on average much larger than pictures, we've started off with pictures.
Making our APIs support uploading large files is something we have on our plates to fix, so you should eventually see support for video added.

Comment: thanks for quick response...hope the video comes soon bc almost a dealbreaker for me without it. Otherwise like the android client.  can't get the photos synced to my pc from cloud yet tho

Comment: FWIW there's now a beta of the Dropbox client which supports auto-upload of both photos and videos.

Answer (score 2):

The app FolderSync claims it can do it. Try it out: [marketlink](https://market.android.com/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiZGsudGFjaXQuYW5kcm9pZC5mb2xkZXJzeW5jLmxpdGUiXQ..)