# Frontend to view Android's videos in Ubuntu

Tags: video, android

I have videos taken by my Android phone Samsung galaxy S4.
I see the device and the memory card in my system. 
I could search those files by `find [/media/] -iregex *.mp4` but I would like to sync those automatically to my system.

I think there is no support for this. 
I could not view those videos directly from phone. 
Ubuntu One also has some critical problems with files as described in the [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61391/why-does-ubuntu-one-android-not-sync-video).

I needed copy those files first to my system and then view them. 
However, the USB connection is unstable. 
It closes and starts peridiocally making copying directly from phone impossible. 
The only choice is to take the memory card directly from phone and insert it to the computer and read it there so you also save the lifetime of your SSD.

How can you view videos from Android in Ubuntu?

Comment: Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid where only USB 3.0 connections. Please, add to the body when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `File Manager` by ZenUI and ASUS in Android phone

[image]

Click `PC file transfer`. Go to the IP-address given by the program on the screen. Control your Android phone with your Ubuntu and view videos.

My phone: Samsung Galaxy S4 gt-i9506 with Temasek's Rom of CyanogenMod13

Answer (score 2):

I had the same unstable USB connection problem with my S4. I found that it doesn’t like the 3.0 ports. If you have a 2.0 USB port, use that one instead and I think you’ll do better uploading your videos. I use the VLC media player to view my android videos and it works great for me. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Great addition! My laptop has only USB 3.0 connections. Nice catch!